# SVG Animations pattern edge

Tags: svg, jquery-animate

I want to create stripe animated background but for some reason can't remove vertical lines that appear on the edge of patterns.

Here is my svg:

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
      <defs>
  <linearGradient id='stripe-gradient' x1='0%' y1='0%' x2='100%' y2='100%'>
             <stop offset='0%'  stop-color='#AAA'></stop>
    <stop offset='24.9%'  stop-color='#AAA'></stop>
             <stop offset='25%' stop-color='#666'></stop>
    <stop offset='49.9%' stop-color='#666'></stop>
    <stop offset='50%' stop-color='#AAA'></stop>
    <stop offset='74.9%' stop-color='#AAA'></stop>
    <stop offset='75%' stop-color='#666'></stop>
    <stop offset='99.9%' stop-color='#666'></stop>
    <stop offset='100%' stop-color='#AAA'></stop>
  </linearGradient>
        <pattern id='stripe-pattern' width='20' height='20' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' >
     <rect x='-20' y='0' width='20' height='20' fill='url(#stripe-gradient)' stroke-width='0' stroke='none'>
      <animate attributeName='x' from='-20' to='0' dur='0.5s' repeatCount='indefinite'></animate>
     </rect>
           <rect x='0' y='0' width='20' height='20' fill='url(#stripe-gradient)' stroke-width='0' stroke='none'>
      <animate attributeName='x' from='0' to='20' dur='0.5s' repeatCount='indefinite'></animate>
     </rect>
        </pattern>
        <mask id='stripe-mask'>
          <rect x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%' fill='url(#stripe-pattern)' ></rect>
        </mask>      
      </defs>
      <rect class="hbar thing" x="0" y="0" width="200" fill="green" height="200" mask="url(#stripe-mask)"></rect>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is a bit old but in case you still need to solve this issue I have made it work by doubling the stripes, removing one of the rects inside the pattern and then doubling the size of the last rect, c.f., the following code:

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id='stripe-gradient' x1='0%' y1='0%' x2='100%' y2='100%'>
            <stop offset='0%'  stop-color='#AAA'></stop>
            <stop offset='12.45%'  stop-color='#AAA'></stop>
            <stop offset='12.5%' stop-color='#666'></stop>
            <stop offset='24.45%' stop-color='#666'></stop>
            <stop offset='25.5%'  stop-color='#AAA'></stop>
            <stop offset='37.45%'  stop-color='#AAA'></stop>
            <stop offset='37.5%' stop-color='#666'></stop>
            <stop offset='49.9%' stop-color='#666'></stop>
            <stop offset='50%' stop-color='#AAA'></stop>
            <stop offset='62.45%' stop-color='#AAA'></stop>
            <stop offset='62.5%' stop-color='#666'></stop>
            <stop offset='74.95%' stop-color='#666'></stop>
            <stop offset='75%' stop-color='#AAA'></stop>
            <stop offset='87.45%' stop-color='#AAA'></stop>
            <stop offset='87.5%' stop-color='#666'></stop>
            <stop offset='100%' stop-color='#666'></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <pattern id='stripe-pattern' width='20' height='20' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' >
            <rect x='-20' y='0' width='40' height='40' fill='url(#stripe-gradient)' stroke-width='0' stroke='none'>
                <animate attributeName='x' from='-20' to='0' dur='0.5s' repeatCount='indefinite'></animate>
            </rect>
        </pattern>
        <mask id='stripe-mask'>
            <rect x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%' fill='url(#stripe-pattern)'></rect>
        </mask>      
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" fill="green" height="200" mask="url(#stripe-mask)"></rect>
</svg>
```

I think the vertical stripes appeared as a result of some small numerical issues whenever the browser calculates the position of the two rects. Therefore, the solution is to use only one rect.